# Associate string with function Lua

Tags: lua

I have table like a:

> `{ "video", video_search ( message ) }`.

How can i make check if input string = `"video"` then execute `video_search` command?

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer to your question would be

```lua
if input_string == "video" then
   video_search()
end
```

but going by the title and a fair bit of intuition, I assume you really want to ask

> how do I associate functions with strings and, given a string, call the associated function?

To which the answer is a different one: first, restructure your table so it looks like this

```lua
local whatever = {
   ["video"] = video_search;
   ["audio"] = audio_search;
   -- whatever else you have...
}
```

then you can just call the function like this:

```lua
local input = "video"
local message = "whatever a message is in your program"

whatever[input](message)
```